# Is type(1) the equivalent of type.__call__(1)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I run codes in Jupyter console(Python's version is `2.7.14`),

```
type(1)
Out[71]: int

type.__call__(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-0ed097e2c413> in <module>()
----> 1 type.__call__(1)

TypeError: descriptor '__call__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'int'
```

I've guessed `type(...)` is a equivalent of `type.__call__(...)` but it seems no. So I wonder:

1. What have been done by the python interpreter when I call `type(1)` or `type(name, base, dict)`?
2. When the `type.__call__(...)` will be invoked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version: There are two reasonable things `type.__call__` could resolve to: a bound method representing the method used for calling `type` itself, or an unbound method representing the method used for calling instances of `type`. You're expecting the first result, but what you actually get is the second.

---

Long version:

`some_callable(thing)` is normally equivalent to `some_callable.__call__(thing)`. For example, `print(1)` is equivalent to `print.__call__(1)` (as long as you have `from __future__ import print_function` turned on):

```
>>> print(1)
1
>>> print.__call__(1)
1
```

`type` is a callable, and `type(thing)` *would* be equivalent to `type.__call__(thing)`, except that attribute lookup runs into a complication.

During the `type.__call__` attribute lookup, Python searches `type` and its superclasses (just `object`) for a `__dict__` entry with key `'__call__'`. Python *also* searches `type`'s type and `type`'s type's superclasses for such a `__dict__` entry. (You can see the code responsible for invoking these searches in [`type_getattro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/typeobject.c#L2603), the C function that handles attribute lookup for types.) Since `type` is its own type, both of these searches find `type.__dict__['__call__']`.

One of these searches takes priority. The way the choice is made, and the reason the choice even matters, is the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors). If the first search wins, then the descriptor protocol is applied as normal for finding a class attribute (`descriptor.__get__(None, cls)`); if the second search wins, the descriptor protocol is applied as normal for finding an instance attribute (`descriptor.__get__(instance, cls)`). The second search needs to win for `type.__call__(thing)` to behave like `type(thing)`, but it would only win if `type.__dict__['__call__']` was a *data descriptor*, and it's not.

The first search wins. The descriptor protocol is applied as normal for finding a class attribute, and the result of looking up `type.__call__` is an *unbound* method. It represents the general `__call__` method of instances of `type`, rather than the `__call__` instance method of `type`-as-an-instance-of-type. It would need to be called as

```
type.__call__(type, 1)
```

to be equivalent to `type(1)`.

---

After all that, you might be wondering how `type(thing)` works without running into all those complications. In terms of language semantics, Python only performs the second search when looking up `type`'s `__call__` method to call it, so the first search can't win because it doesn't even happen. In terms of actual implementation, CPython doesn't actually look up the `__call__` method at all; it looks up `type`'s type, goes to the C-level slot on `type`'s type corresponding to `__call__`, and calls [the function it finds](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.15/Objects/typeobject.c#L737). For a `__call__` method implemented in Python, the C slot would contain a function that looks up and calls the Python method, but for a `__call__` implemented in C, the C slot contains the `__call__` implementation directly.

Answer (score 4):

Because `type` is a class, you need its `__new__` method:

```
>>> type.__new__(type, 1)
<type 'int'>
```

Usually, `cls(*args, **kwargs)` is equivalent to `cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` followed by calling `.__init__(*args, **kwargs)` on the returned object.

Here's one possible implementation of this behavior of `type()`:

```
class MyType(object):
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        return obj.__class__

    def __init__(self, hahaha):
        pass
```

See [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397896/5958455) for question 2.

Comment: `cls(*args, **kwargs)` is not equivalent to `cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. Calling a class will normally perform `__init__` after calling `__new__`; it doesn't for `type(1)` because `type.__call__` specifically special-cases one-argument calls to `type` and does not call `__init__` for that case.

Comment: @user2357112 Updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason, as @user2357112 said, is that `type` acts as both a built-in function <sub>(which also doubles as a metaclass but that's not important here)</sub> and a class.

`type(1)`, in accordance with [Built-in Functions — Python 2.7.15 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type), acts as a regular function that returns the type of an object or creates a new custom type object.

```
In [13]: type?
Docstring:
type(object) -> the object's type
type(name, bases, dict) -> a new type
Type:      type
```

- It's implemented by [`typeobject.c:type_call()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L738) which is [specified as `PyType_Type.tp_call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L2894).

`type.__call__`, on the other hand, is an implementation of the call for objects of the class `type` -- i.e. types -- which, as you know, creates an instance of that type. I.e. an unbound method:

```
In [14]: type.__call__?
Type:        wrapper_descriptor
String form: <slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:   x.__call__(...) <==> x(...)
```

- It's implemented by [`typeobject.c:slot_tp_call()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L5600) which is returned on `__call__` attribute lookup, via [`typeobject.c:slotdefs[]`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#L6037) whose contents `type.__dict__` is filled with during initialization.

---

The reason for the difference in execution paths is that attribute lookup is not done in the first case:

```
In [16]: dis.dis(compile("type(1)","<stdin>","eval"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (type)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE

In [17]: dis.dis(compile("type.__call__(1)","<stdin>","eval"))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (type)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__call__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

And [when calling an object like a function, `tp_call` takes priority](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#L2540).

Comment: for `type(x)`, is it [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L1178) line (`Py_TYPE(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0))`) that finds the string representation of the type of `x`? I was hoping to see why `type(foo)` (where `foo` is an instance of user-defined class `Foo`) returns `class '__main__.Foo'`, but cannot find where `Py_TYPE` is implemented.

Comment: @user51462 looks like that. I suggest to run the code under debugger if just looking at the source is insufficient to see what's happening.

Comment: @user51462 By searching the source for "Py_TYPE" and "#define Py_TYPE", I found that it's defined at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a8c15819c27c516e5b75b7c9d89eacdb16b77c3/Include/object.h#L134-L136

Comment: Thanks so much @ivan_pozdeev. I don't know any C so wasn't sure what to search.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second half of your question, since @iBug already answered the first half, `type.__call__` is a method of `type`, so instead of `type.__call__(1)`, you should call it as a bound method:

```
self = type(1)
self.__call__(1)
```

or:

```
type.__call__(type(1), 1)
```

both of which returns:

```
type(1).__new__(type(1), 1)
```

which is really `int(1)` since `type(1)` returns `int`.